# Merging tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server that I want to merge.

The first table is `dbo.bac` and has a column `counter`, the second table is `dbo.data` and also has a column `counter`.

I want to load the first table and the second table with all their columns that have the same `counter` value. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'merge'?  It has a specific meaning in T-SQL, is this what you intend?

Comment: You can use join to merge tables in sql.

Comment: gees at least make an effort - show your tables, some sample data, a desired result, and some attempt.

Comment: The first table dbo.bac and a counter column named counter the second table dbo.data and a counter column named also counter I want to load the first table and the second table with all it's column that have the same counter number. Thanks fo the help...

Comment: Check out this link to know more on how to ask questions :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` to join both tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.bac A
INNER JOIN dbo.data B ON B.counter = A.counter
```

this should do it, but you need to filter your records as needed.